# How to close current fold when foldopen=all?

Tags: folding

I have a setup where I want folds to open whenever the cursor moves into a fold, including through vertical motion. I have `set foldopen=all`.

However, I also want to manually close folds as it makes some actions easier like deleting a whole fold. However, `zc` does nothing.

I've tried setting `foldopen` with the list of every item but `all`. This does allow closing folds, but this doesn't open a fold on vertical motions.

How can I have both folds that open on vertical motions but allow manually closing folds that I'm in.

Comment: What remain unclear to me is how you plan to do some action on the whole fold with the fold getting expanded with every vertical movement (see the NOTE in `:help 'foldopen'`).

Comment: I guess that's a question of timing. If the fold is closed, and I type `dd` does that delete the fold immediately, or open the fold and then delete it?
The note about a mapping gave me the idea to have `zc` be in a mapping to ignore foldopen, but that didn't work.